# How to rebalance a dataset for a logit model in Stata?

Tags: stata, logit, rare-events

I want to use logit model in Stata. In my dataset only 3% of my target variable observations are 1, and 97% are 0.

How do I rebalance this data set, so I have more observations labelled 1, and fewer labelled 0?

Comment: Throwing away some zeros or getting more ones are generally poor solutions for this.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what rebalance means exactly. One solution to this type of problem is Gary King's [rare events logit code for Stata](http://gking.harvard.edu/relogit). It's also available for Gauss, and in R though Zelig. He also provided some advice on sampling, which you might find useful.

He (and co-authors) write:

> First, popular statistical procedures, such as logistic regression,
>   can sharply underestimate the probability of rare events. We recommend
>   corrections that outperform existing methods and change the estimates
>   of absolute and relative risks by as much as some estimated effects
>   reported in the literature. Second, commonly used data collection
>   strategies are grossly inefficient for rare events data. The fear of
>   collecting data with too few events has led to data collections with
>   huge numbers of observations but relatively few, and poorly measured,
>   explanatory variables, such as in international conflict data with
>   more than a quarter-million dyads, only a few of which are at war. As
>   it turns out, more efficient sampling designs exist for making valid
>   inferences, such as sampling all variable events (e.g., wars) and a
>   tiny fraction of nonevents (peace).

Other options are exact logistic regression (`exlogistic`) and penalized MLE (`firthlogit`). The former is really suitable only if you have small samples with a small number of discrete covariates.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your dataset, that's your dataset to analyse.  You could throw away some of the zeroes, to get further from 3%. But you can't change your data, because then your analyses aren't valid.

BUT - there's no reason that this is a problem (assuming your sample size is large enough. Analyze away!

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said, it shouldn't be a problem if your sample size is large enough, I should think.

I don't know much about it myself, but the Tobit model may be appropriate here?

Comment: Tobits are used when the outcome is censored above or below some threshold. For example, we don't observe any wages below the minimum wage or incomes above some top coded value. They are not relevant for a binary outcome like this.

Comment: Ah, thanks for commenting. For some reason, I thought it was for responses that tend to cluster.